# Can APK deactivated in Play console be retained?

Tags: android, console, playback

I created a new android release in the Google Play Console. In the process I forgot to click the "Retain" button on the old APK. I didn't notice my mistake until I started to rollout the new release (which I immediately halted). I cannot find a way to edit the new rollout to retain the old APK from the current release. Is there way to fix this problem?

The reason I need to retain the old APK is that the new one does not support older SDKs.

Comment: So far I have not found a way to fix this problem. I had to rebuild the old and new APKs with new version numbers. Then I uploaded both to a new release. There should be a way in the console to fix this mistake, but sadly it is not yet there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by choosing Create Release, then Choose APK From Library, thus "republishing" your previous version.
To be honest, I did not think of it myself, it was suggested by Google Play support.